# Android studio views with same id

Tags: android, listview, button, android-studio

I'm using android studio and I have problem.

In activity A, I have added Button and made its id **btnCreateOrJoin**. After that I create activity B and added ListView and made its id **listAnswers**. When I go back to activity A, my button now has id **listAnswers**. I change it back to **btnCreateOrJoin** now when I open activity B, ListView now has id **btnCreateOrJoin**.

Question: is it BUG or my error? How can I avoid this?

Images:

Changed button to **btnCreateOrJoin**:
[image]

ListView now has id **btnCreateOrJoin**:
[image]

Version of Android-studio is 0.8.6

Comment: The failure is on your side. Are you talking about java or xml code?

Comment: This happens when I drag views to my layout

Comment: What? Can we see your xml or java code where you are handling these? This shouldn't happen unless you are doing something funny.

Comment: I am simple dragging views and setting ids on different activities. This happens often, I always need to delete and recreate views on layouts.

Comment: I don't use the WYSIWYG editor, but I am assuming your views that you drag/drop are synced. Changing one changes the other. Instead of copy/pasting (drag/drop) your views, create a new view.

Comment: 0.8.6 is quite an old build, have you tried the released version (1.0)